# Jquery $(this).val(); on .ready not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, selected

I'm trying to get the value of a dropdown's option (there is an id on the select markup), when opening the web page

Using

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cat_list').ready(function(){
  var category =  $(this).val();
  alert(category);
  });

});
```

I get a blank alert.

But Using .change (when selecting something else inside the dropdown) the following code works perfectly with the same function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cat_list').change(function(){
  var category =  $(this).val();
  alert(category);
  });

});
```

Finally, this works using basic javascript and it gets successfully the values on open, refresh, on form submit fail, ... etc

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cat_list').ready(function(){
  var e = document.getElementById("cat_list");
  var category = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
  alert(category);
  });

});
```

Thanks for any help on why the first version .ready + $(this).val();  fails

Comment: Can't you just use $('#cat_list') instead of $(this)? It'll be fine as long as you work with id.

Comment: Check the DOC: <<The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted.>>  http://api.jquery.com/ready/   In your code, 'this' refers to document

Comment: You don't need `ready` callback for your element because you are already using it dor `document`

Comment: you don't have to check ` $('#cat_list').ready(function(){` when it is inside document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var category = $('#cat_list').val();
    alert(category);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready itself means the whole document (including #cat_list) is ready to be processed. why are you checking if an element is ready or not!!??

you can directly use the value of the element like

`$('#cat_list').val();`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that `.ready`:

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

And 3 possible usage cases are:

- $(document).ready(handler)
- $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
- $(handler)

However you can actually assign `.ready` to any element and it will be triggered:

```
$('#cat_list').ready(function(){

});
```

This code is fired. **BUT** `this` inside `.ready` function always refers to `document`.

It will work this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cat_list').ready(function(){
      var category =  $('#cat_list').val();
      alert(category);
  });
});
```

But actually your code is overengineered:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var category =  $('#cat_list').val();
    alert(category);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time helping a newbie :) that helped me understand what I was doing wrong